# Replacing possible constants in a variable

Tags: php, constants, str-replace

I have loads of constants set.
I have phrases from database that might have those constant names in them.

I want to replace the constants names with their values.

```
Constants:
Array
(
[WORK1] => Pizza Delivery
[WORK2] => Chauffer
[WORK3] => Package Delivery
)
```

Variables:

```
$variable[0] = "I like doing WORK1";
$variable[1] = "Nothing here move along";
$variable[2] = "WORK3 has still not shown up.";
```

How would I get those variables with the right constant vales on them? Constants order could be unsorted as well as variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be as simple as:

```
foreach ($variable as &$v)
{
  $v = str_replace(array_keys($constants), array_values($constants), $v);
}
unset($v);
```

Note that it is probably more optimal to do something like this before the loop:

```
$keys = array_keys($constants);
$vals = array_values($constants);
```

And then use them directly instead of calling array_key/vals during every iteration.

And on second thought, this is probably best:

```
foreach ($variable as &$v)
{
  $v = strtr($v, $constants);
}
unset($v);
```

because it doesn't process first to last, and you should get consistent behavior regardless of how the constants are sorted.

Comment: thats great, it works :) However works better than i want lol. Anyway to only replace with the constants names that start with "WORK"? Because right now its replacing other characters i dont want since the get_defined_constants(); array is quite big.

Comment: @Joan, you may find it better to use something like `%WORK1%` as the placeholder, to limit the number of unintended replacements. You'd just have to first cycle through the constant keys and alter them as needed.